# Does Caffe "ImageNet" support .jpg or .bmp images?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, imagenet

Does Caffe "ImageNet" support `.jpg` or `.bmp` images as input?
In ILSVRC2012, I see only `.JPEG` files.  I tried to train models on .jpg and .bmp files (different train for each type), but it doesn't give reasonable results.

Comment: First, let's clarify the terminology.  "ImageNet" is the organization that sponsors ILSVRC (That's the **I** in the abbreviation).  The ImageNet data set's most-used version is the one provided for the 2012 and later contests, named **ILSVRC2012**.  This data set consists of .JPEG files.  Caffe is developed by BVLC, not ImageNet; I'm confused by your phrase 'caffe "ImageNet"', because the two are independent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just new with this topic. I just followed the train orders from Caffe official website. when I checked my results (in classify test) as this examples:./build/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin 
  `models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt 
  models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel 
  data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto 
  data/ilsvrc12/synset_words.txt 
  examples/images/cat.jpg`
and the classification doesn't work, no matter what image i put for this test, the results (of classification) are same numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on to my comment above ...

The Caffe release includes several popular models that you can train with ImageNet data.  The input layers of these models assume a consistent format, usually either JPEG or LMDB.  An input layer that accepts one format is not useful for an incompatible format, such as BMP.

If you want to accept BMP input instead, you have to specify or write a different input layer.  If you want to accept both JPEG and BMP in the same training run, you have to set up separate input processing for the two formats to get them into a compatible form.

Comment: thanks for comment. I made an LMDB file from .jpg images make the Mean file from the LMDB but it won't work. then I made some little experience with .bmp files but it still doesn't work.. so I thought their net work only with .JPEG files.

Comment: You are correct that far: the code, as given, works only with JPEG files.  If you want it to work with BMP, you have to write some code to process those files.